# CSS Tabs in emails

Tags: css, html, email

I am trying to create an email template for my site, in the template i need CSS tabs that work even without JavaScript,

I have css tabs like that:

Styling:

```
#globalnav {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    padding:0 0 1.75em 1em;
    margin:0;
    list-style:none;
    line-height:1em;
}

#globalnav LI {
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#globalnav A {
    display:block;
    color:#444;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:#ddd;
    margin:0;
    padding:0.25em 1em;
    border-left:1px solid #fff;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
    border-right:1px solid #aaa;
}

#globalnav A:hover,
#globalnav A:active,
#globalnav A.here:link,
#globalnav A.here:visited {
    background:#bbb;
}

#globalnav A.here:link,
#globalnav A.here:visited {
    position:relative;
    z-index:102;
}

/*subnav*/

#globalnav UL {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:1.5em;
    float:left;
    background:#bbb;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0.25em 0.25em 0.25em 1em;
    list-style:none;
    border-top:1px solid #fff;
}

#globalnav UL LI {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    margin-top:1px;
}

#globalnav UL A {
    background:#bbb;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline;
    margin:0;
    padding:0 1em;
    border:0
}

#globalnav UL A:hover,
#globalnav UL A:active,
#globalnav UL A.here:link,
#globalnav UL A.here:visited {
    color:#444;
}
```

Code in html:

```
  <ul id="globalnav">
                                <li><a href="#" class="here">INFOmail Hoy</a>


                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Vieron</a>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">OTFs</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Eventos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">ECos</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Encuetams</a></li>

                            </ul>
```

But this doesn't really work out for me, because it does not change or do anything when you click or move on to it.

I can't get it do work so that it will really be tabs, i.e. changing the content when clicked. I need it to work on email clients like gmail or outlook.

Comment: How did you include the CSS? And why are all the elements in your CSS in caps?

Comment: Email templates are not as flexible as a regular web page. You won't probably be able to use any kind of Javascript. Keep the layout as simple as possible. Maybe even use tables, to make sure it'll be accessible on pre-historic versions of Outlook, etc.

Comment: as far as I know, this would not work. Because in html e-mails you can only use table layout for all e-mail clients. Also web based clients behave in the same way. Old html and its style is used here.

Comment: The CSS rules should be included as part of its body. Forget about headers. If they don't seem to work, include them inline in the elements. It's a pain, I know, but that's the way it is unfortunately.

Comment: guys, this one looks great on any kind of email program, i checked it, the only thing is, how can i make it to change (putvande - the style is a part of the body)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create tabs in emails just by using CSS - except they won't work in all clients so you need to evaluate your "fallback" strategies as well as whether its worth it.

The following article shows you how to create tabs that work in the iOS, Android native email clients as well as Yahoo! Mail, Gmail and AOL Mail. Specifically these tabs won't work in Outlook.com or Outlook.

http://freshinbox.com/blog/interactive-tabs-for-email/

As dcc mentioned a lot of the clients don't support certain CSS styles such as positioning so the example avoids them by using alternative "tricks" such as using labels, checkboxes and nesting.

Comment: >  evaluate your "fallback" strategies _as well as whether its worth it_

Old answer, but just adding that this should be always kept in mind with emails. Oftentimes, I've dealt with issues that were "not worth" the payoff, but assumed they "should be" kept as that's how the PSD/design comp was originally.

Answer (score 1):

This is just plain a bad idea unless you do not care that the vast majority of people receiving your email are going to receive an email which looks very bad.

CSS positioning does not work in HTML email.  I reviewed your code snippet and would suggest you delete it.  You have not written a single CSS definition that should exist in an email.  Positioning,margin, and padding elements to name a few don't work in emails and basic styling such as background-color, and color should be written inline.

If you'd like a good template, here is a very good one you can review:  [gist(link)](https://gist.github.com/dcondrey/727145a5d161c9475558)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is currently rather impossible to have CSS-only tabs that are cross-browser compatible.

This is about the closest thing you can get:

```
HTML
<div class="tabs">
  <div class="tab"><div class="tab-box"></div></div>
  <div class="tab"><div class="tab-box"></div></div>
  <div class="tab active"><div class="tab-box"></div></div>
  <div class="tab"><div class="tab-box"></div></div>

</div>
  <div class="content">

  </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  padding:100px;
}
.tabs {
  height:45px;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  overflow:visible;
}
.tab {
  width:200px;
  height:45px;
  overflow:hidden;
  float:left;
  margin:0 -15px 0 0;
}


.tab-box {
  height:50px;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  margin:0 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px  #fff inset;


 -webkit-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);
 -moz-transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(30deg);

}

.tab.active {
  z-index:40;
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:1px;
}
.tab.active .tab-box{
  background-color: #eee;
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(top, #ccc , #ddd 3%, rgba(#eee, 0.5)  ));
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 0 #fff inset;
}

.content {
  z-index:1;
  padding:100px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#eee;
  position:relative;

}

.clear {
 clear:both;
}
```

JS

```
$('.tab').click(function(){
  $('.tab').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Demo:
http://codepen.io/minipai/pen/Etnhv

You might also want to take a look at 
https://github.com/adamschwartz/chrome-tabs

Comment: Not sure why you posted this since this requires Javascript and won't work with email.